# Xcode Storyboard Image Sizing

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, xcode-storyboard

I cannot figure out how the image inside this imageview is behaving the way it is.  It goes out of bounds, and does not scale the way other imageviews do.

Here it is in three different fills: scale to fill, aspect fit, and aspect fill.  None of these sizings are how any other image would be sized.  I've adjusted the imageview with different constraints, no constraints, different alignments, no alignments, etc., but the image doesn't change its behavior at all.

My current Xcode version is Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)

The dimensions of that box are 374 x 266.

The natural size of the image is 320 x 569.

Here is what I'm working with:

Scale to Fill:

[image: Scale to Fill]

Aspect Fit:

[image: Aspect Fit]

Aspect Fill:

[image: Aspect Fill]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like constraint of ImageView is not correct. Try to give Width Constraint to 374(or as per ur requirement ) and Height Constraint to 266(or as per ur requirement ), Top or Bottom, Leading or trailing constraint as per the requirement.